# Migrating data and removing them

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql

I am working on a Oracle database. There's a table called USR_INFO.

It has many columns like,

1. USR_ID
2. USR_NAME
3. USR_TYPE
4. USR_PW

and more.........

Now i want to create a new table called USR_SUPER and copy some data from the USR_INFO into it.

The condition for copying is, if USR_TYPE is equal to "S", then copy the corresponding
USR_ID and USR_PW to new table called USR_SUPER.

So there're  3 steps involved in it.

1. Create table called USR_SUPER.
2. Move data from USR_INFO table if USR_TYPE == "S", to USR_SUPER table columns USR_S_ID & USR_S_PW.
3. Remove every moved data from USR_INFO table.

I am new to SQL and don't know how to do this.

Can somone provide me with the SQL for doing these 3 steps?

This is what i did so far:

```
// To create new table called USR_SUPER
CREATE TABLE USR_SUPER (USR_S_ID int, USR_S_PW varchar(50));

// To move data to new table if USR_TYPE == "S"
INSERT INTO USR_SUPER (USR_S_ID, USR_S_PW)
SELECT USR_ID, USR_PW
FROM USR_INFO
WHERE USR_TYPE="S";
```

// How to remove data that has already been moved?

Comment: If you are using Oracle, why MySQL and SQL Server tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***NOTE*** : The following will definitely work in `SQL Server` and might need might minor modification to work in Oracle. The idea remains the same though.

You can do it this way :

**Step 1:** Create table called `USR_SUPER`.

```
CREATE TABLE usr_super(USR_S_ID INT, USR_S_PW INT)
```

**Step 2:** Move data from `USR_INFO` table if `USR_TYPE` == "S", to `USR_SUPER` table columns `USR_S_ID` & `USR_S_PW`.

```
INSERT INTO usr_super (USR_S_ID, USR_S_PW) (SELECT          inf.USR_ID,
                                                            inf.USR_PW
                                             FROM           usr_info inf
                                             WHERE          inf.USR_TYPE = 's')
```

**Step 3:** Remove every moved data from `USR_INFO` table.

```
DELETE FROM     usr_info
WHERE           usr_id IN (SELECT   usr_s_id
                           FROM     usr_super)
```

So, essentially your complete code will be :

```
CREATE TABLE usr_super(USR_S_ID INT, USR_S_PW INT)          //Step 1
INSERT INTO usr_super (USR_S_ID, USR_S_PW) (SELECT          inf.USR_ID,
                                                            inf.USR_PW
                                             FROM           usr_info inf
                                             WHERE          inf.USR_TYPE = 's')    //Step 2
DELETE FROM     usr_info
WHERE           usr_id IN (SELECT   usr_s_id
                           FROM     usr_super)         //Step 3
```

Comment: For step #3, is it possible to look for USR_TYPE == "S" and then delete the entire row?

Comment: @Donsan Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps, first you select the records INTO the new table (this creates the table on the fly) and then you delete all the records from the USR_INFO table by filtering by all the USR_IDs in the new table:

```
SELECT USR_ID, USR_PW
INTO USR_SUPER
FROM USR_INFO
WHERE USR_TYPE="S";

DELETE FROM USR_INFO WHERE USR_ID IN (SELECT USR_ID FROM USR_SUPER)
```

If you really want another column name for the password column on the new table, you can define an alias when selecting the records into the new table like this:

```
SELECT USR_ID 'USR_S_ID', USR_PW 'USR_S_PWD'
INTO USR_SUPER
FROM USR_INFO
WHERE USR_TYPE="S";
```

**UPDATE**

After reading about the [SELECT INTO on oracle databases](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm) I've realized that there are some differences to MS SQL when it comes to this command. It looks like you would have to do a `BULK COLLECT INTO` if you have multiple matching rows. So it would become:

```
SELECT USR_ID 'USR_S_ID', USR_PW 'USR_S_PWD'
BULK COLLECT INTO USR_SUPER
FROM USR_INFO
WHERE USR_TYPE="S";
```

Hope that works for you.